# CQRS+Event Sourcing as Top Level Architecture: Anti-Pattern

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, anti-patterns, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have been study DDD along with CQRS and Event Sourcing. I recently listened to a talk Greg Young gave a couple years ago where he said that CQRS and Event Sourcing are not a top level architecture and should be used within the confines of specific bounded contexts. Doing otherwise would be an anti-pattern.

This makes a lot of sense in general, however it seems to conflict with what I perceived to be one of the benefits of an event sourced system: being able to have different context-specific aggregate roots of the same "thing" in different contexts, each reconstructed from the same event stream.

For example a `Customer` would have different implementation in different contexts (Ordering, Marketing/Product Recommendations, Customer Service, Authentication), however certain events would be relevant across multiple contexts (eg. `CustomerEmailChanged` would be relevant to Marketing, Customer Service, and Authentication. `OrderPlaced` would be relevant to Ordering and Marketing).

Prior to listening to that talk, my plan was to have these different contexts share an event store and just ignore events that were not relevant. And that stills seems like a very reasonable way to handle that, but I also can kind of see how this could be an anti-pattern, blurring the lines between various bounded contexts.

What would be the correct way to go about this, or is my approach altogether flawed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason ES is generally not a good idea for top-level architecture ("anti-pattern" has no real meaning anymore) is because it's complicated. Plain and simple.

An ES system is *going* to be more difficult to conceptualize and develop than a traditional system backed by an RDBMS. Think about it. You are essentially adding another, lower layer (a new "truth") to your application along with all of the plumbing necessary to "project" that layer upward towards your domain. This is not trivial. Not only will you likely lose many of the built-in benefits an RDBMS can provide regarding constraints, type checking, and normalization of your data (an event store is usually a little more free-form), you need to account for things like possible future changes (versioning) and the headache of "retroactively" modifying your event store when you realize you need to fundamentally change some behavior (I promise you this *will* happen for any non-trivial system). Taken as a whole, ES presents a system that is harder to understand, harder to manage, and harder to change (this may seem like a point of contention, but a well-designed traditional DDD system is easier to change. That's the whole point of DDD right?).

On the other side of the coin, most of the benefits of ES are high-level in nature (introducing another layer to your application certainly doesn't benefit developers). One of the biggest benefits is that ES systems are easier to scale. A single, append-only store with separate read/write models can be scaled with ease. Additionally, as @Ewan alluded to, because your domain is simply a projection of the event store (that is, because you have added another layer), ES systems afford the ability to easily create many different projections of your data (a new command model can emerge without having to make DB schema changes, for example). This can be useful for data warehousing/analytics, but also can help with future-proofing your application.

Now, with the above in mind, we can clearly see that the benefits of an ES system are orthogonal to it's drawbacks: high-level benefits, low-level drawbacks. This is in direct contrast to most other architectures: DDD is all about creating a system that is simple to develop and change at the cost of possible difficulties in scaling etc. This is generally a better trade-off for software systems because they tend to evolve over time, hardware is cheap, and most applications simply don't require a massive scale/throughput.

As such, ES should applied *when necessary* to help solve a specific problem/domain, not blindly to an entire application (pet projects exempt).

EDIT - As to the question regarding "sharing" events between contexts. Each context needs to "own" it's changes. You don't want a change in one context to directly create a change in another. Doing so will couple them together which defeats the entire purpose of creating two contexts in the first place. This is akin to having two aggregates depend on the same field in a RDBMS. I think you may be misunderstanding the benefit you outline regarding the reconstruction of different models from your event stream. This DOES NOT APPLY to command models. You may only have ONE command model per event stream. Business rules cannot be selectively enforced. And to that end, multiple read models are possible in any system.

More specifically, ask yourself "why" your `EmailChanged` event is relevant to more than one context. Could it be possible that you haven't divided your contexts appropriately? It looks like you have created contexts around organizational boundaries. This often creates problems. Here is a short discussion of the topic:

http://udidahan.com/2016/02/19/ask-udi-two-services-operating-on-the-same-entity/

It's important to understand that your entities and bounded contexts will often be "discovered", not decided upon based on some holistic knowledge of your business. Model according to behavior!

Comment: After 5 years of building distributed occasionally disconnected systems based on event sourcing, and many years of CRUD development prior to that, I can tell you that event sourcing introduces a lot of low-level complexities (read my blog posts [here](https://www.continuousimprover.com/tags/#event-sourcing_)). However, this is just a _different_ kind of complexity than what you face when you build a domain that needs to map to an RDBMS. It's not _more_ complexity.

Comment: @DennisDoomen I agree ES introduces a different kind of complexity, but that complexity is additive. That is, *in addition to* the complexities of managing/persisting a domain model, ES adds complexity to persistence/management. Imagine a system with a single entity. Certainly it is less complex to read/write to this entity using a CRUD approach than ES. As my post explains, the addition of all the complexities of ES (schema, versioning, etc) is justified when the benefits (history, auditing, scaling) are necessary. This is precisely why ES is not a good fit for a top-level architecture.

Comment: Although I agree with most of what you're saying, I've seen many teams fail in trying to effectively map a domain model to a RDBMS using an OR/M. Loads of performance problems and other impedance mismatches.

Comment: @DennisDoomen If an ORM is not the right tool for the job, it should not be used. I don't find an ORM particularly useful in a DDD system anyway due to the additional mapping required from the data model an ORM necessitates to the domain model and visa versa. Impedance mismatch is orthogonal to the use of an ORM and can exist in any system backed by an RDBMS (graph vs tabular). In any case, modeling is hard. I've seen teams fail in all sorts of ways. The reason is always the same: a lack of understanding.

Comment: @king-side-slide wait a minute. so you are saying that it's the event sourcing that can't be a top level architecture but CQRS can be? I also watched that talk (Greg Young) on youtube very recently and he says CQRS is not a fit for top level. Im confused.

Comment: @SimpleFellow Sorry if I was unclear. Both CQRS and ES are *patterns* that can be employed when the use-case develops within a system. As such, adopting either one should be justified. That said, I find CQRS much easier to justify as its intent is to mitigate the complexity associated with adopting a combined write/read model.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will have some pain at first, but not a fraction of the cumulative pain you will endure from maintaining an UN-SOLID monolith as it gets more and more complex.

CQRS and Event Sourcing is the most natural implementation of non-trivial business models. Think of EVERYTHING that happens around you every day. Nothing starts without a trigger (Command) and everything leads to a series of Events. The notion that a domain model consists of only Classes and Relationships is a relic from the 90’s when database persistence was in it’s infancy.

If you compose your models of Entities, Relationships, Aggregate Roots, Value Object’s, Commands and Events, the following starts to happen:

1. You get greater Single Responsibility because the workload gets spread to where it should be. (Big bloated controller’s in MVC anyone :-)
2. Almost half of your bugs are caused by objects not being in their expected state. Since Event Sourcing breaks up your mammoth classes and leads you to immutability, you will have fewer bugs.
3. You get semi-decent workflow for free.
4. You can ask complicated questions of your data (which item in my store gets added and then removed the most?)
5. You get Auditing for free.
6. You get great performance by preparing your view models with Projections.
7. All-round maintainability is generally better.
8. Testing is easier (setting up integration testing data is much easier)

> An ES system is going to be more difficult to conceptualize

On the contrary, It's way more intuitive for complex models.

> Not only will you likely lose many of the built-in benefits

You want to get rid of them, they are holding you back on the Command side. They are still your friend on the Query side.

> because your domain is simply a projection of the event store

Your event store IS your domain model, spread over time. Projections are view models, de-normalized data sets that you present to clients.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is flawed.

Consider a business rule for the 'sales context'

> If a customer changes their email, they are credited £10

The 'sales context' Customer applies this credit when the Email is set and reconstitutes itself correctly from the EmailChanged event

The 'account context' Customer however is ignoring EmailChanged events. When it was programmed the £10 rule had not been invented. So it does not change and the customer's balance is incorrect when viewed by the accounts application.

By populating two distinct objects from the events you are doing exactly that. You don't have two 'views' of the same Customer you have two alternate universe Customers. Each looking as it would if only a subset of your business rules existed.

**Edit - summary of comment discussion**

It seems your view is that Events should only ever do a single thing when applied to an Object, updating a property to the value stored in the event.

If something does more than a single thing it is a Command, and may generate multiple Events. ie EmailChanged, AccountIncremented

My view is that this misses a huge chunk of Event Sourcing, namely that the function applying an event to a model can be anything you like. When an EmailChanged event is applied to a Customer, leaving aside the domain boundary challenging account example, you might:

- trim spaces from the end of the address
- split the address into username and domain
- add the old address to a list of old email addresses
- set or reset an InvaildEmail flag

Note that these are all internal changes to the Customer object. They don't generate new events and if they did it would be problematic.

The flaw in your ignoring events approach is that you assume that an event is bounded to a domain and could never have a cross domain effect.

Yes good design suggests that if changing an email address credits the customer account, then it *should* trigger an *External* AccountCredit event which is passed to the account domain as in your command example.

But then I chose an obvious example. Who is to say that there isn't a more subtle error, maybe there is an extra fraud check when the InvalidEmail flag is set for example

Comment: Could not that business rule in the Sales context either generate an `AccountCredited(10)` event or somehow issue the relevant command to the Account context? The Account context would only care that the account was credited, not what caused it.

Comment: no, because then you would confuse the event source events and events. when you reconstitute the customer you would get duplication

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. The only "events" in this situation are event source events.

Comment: in which case you can't have your objects create more in response to one. You need to understand the difference between general events in your solution and the event stream you use to persist the object

Comment: The `AccountCredited(10)` event and the `EmailChanged` event would both be generated as a result of some `ChangeCustomerEmail` command issued to the Sales context, not one as a reaction to the other. I'm not sure what you mean by "general event". The only events I have talked about are the event sourcing events used to persist the object.

Comment: thats two types of event, the external incoming command and the changes it triggers. but if you take this approach for everything you limit your objects to simple POCOs with no logic. Usually with event sourcing a single event can trigger multiple internal changes in an object

Comment: How does this limit me to logicless POCOs? A command comes in (calling a command an "event" here seems to just confuse semantics; they aren't stored in the event store and are the 'C' from CQRS), a command handler loads the appropriate aggregate's events from the event store to reconstruct its current state, and then calls the appropriate method on the aggregate. The aggregate executes all the business logic defined in it, generating the appropriate events to represent what happened, and then those events get persisted in the event store. All the business logic lives inside the aggregate class

Comment: That's not how event sourcing works. If you don't believe me, try it.

Comment: What specifically is incorrect in my understanding of how event sourcing works? I have tried it as described in my previous comments within a small test application and it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: 1. save and load the object. no additional events should be created. 2. change the business logic and reconstitute the object from the event store. the object should be correct as per the new rules.

Comment: Both point are consistent with my understanding of event sourcing. How the example in my previous comment violate either point?

Comment: in your example the pre business rule change 'command' generates and stores single event. if you change the object to increase the balance in response to that event by adding a new event then you fail rule 1. if you change the command to generate two events, rather than the object you fail rule 2. if you change the object to increase the balance without writing an event then that doesnt happen if you ignore the previously unrelated to balance event

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by your first rule? Perhaps I misunderstood. Regarding failing rule 2, I disagree. The "credit account $10 when customer email changed" rule shouldn't be retroactively applied to all email changed events that occurred prior to the rule existing. It should only apply to email changes that happen while that rule is active.

Comment: rule one is pretty short. If you make a new Account(+10) event every time you load an object with a EmailChanged event obviously its non-idempotent, if you load it twice you get +20

Comment: in regards to disagreeing with failing rule 2, A. its my example I get to choose what the rule is B. if all your business logic is in the command then you have the logicless POCOs I refered to earlier

Comment: Where did I ever say a new `AccountCredited(10)` event is created every time the object is loaded? And commands contain no business logic, they are essentially a POCO holding the details of the action the client is performing on the system (eg. `ChangeCustomerEmail(customerId = "...", newEmail = "...")`). These details would be handed off by the command handler to the domain object to actually do the work, and generate the relevant events to represent what happened (eg. `Customer customer = getCustomerById(command.customerId); customer.changeEmail(command.newEmail);`

Comment: "aggregate executes all the business logic defined in it, generating the appropriate events to represent what happened"

Comment: All business rules regarding changing the email would be handled internally by the `Customer` object.

Comment: so how will the customer object handle the customer.account +=10 when the email changes without breaking the 2 rules i mentioned?

Comment: But you wouldn't call `customer.ChangeEmail()` when reconstructing the object from the event store, you'd have something like `customer.ApplyEvent(customerEmailChanged())`, which would only play back the existing event, it would never generate new events.

Comment: that breaks rule 2 in one of the three ways I list

Comment: Prior to the account+=10 on email change business rule existing, `customer.ChangeEmail()` would add one event, `customerEmailChanged`, to the event store. Once the rule is added to the customer object, any subsequent calls to `customer.changeEmail()` will result in 2 events being added, `customerEmailChanged` and `customerAccountCredited(10)`. When reconstructing a customer object from the event store, we apply all the relevant events for that object to get its current state based on the history of what happened to that object (ie. the events).

Comment: that breaks rule 2 in that the object will not have the +10 account applied if it was created before the new rule

Comment: Exactly, it shouldn't have that +10 applied because that rule did not exist at the time the email was changed. What you're proposing is changing what should be an append-only history of the object, which violates everything I have read about event sourcing. If for whatever reason the business does want to retroactively apply the +10 credit, a one time operation could be run to find all email changed events prior to the rule existing and then apply the appropriate `AccountCredited(10)` events.

Comment: Then you have lost what many consider to be a key aspect of event sourcing and all your events are essentially dumb 'property X is now Y'. If a retroactive account increment is conceptually too far fetched, consider: "When a customer sets their email address, trailing spaces should be trimmed"

Comment: to quote MF (urgh) "Bug fixes occur when you look at past processing and realize it was incorrect. For internal stuff this is really easy to fix, all you need to do is make the fix and reprocess the events. Your application state is now fixed to what it should have been. For many situations this is really rather nice."

Comment: Assuming the business logic in the customer object handles the trimming rather than requiring that the email address be pre-trimmed, easy: iterate through every customer in the system, calling `customer.setEmail(customer.getEmail())`. Corrective `customerEmailChanged` events will be created where needed, and we don't have to violate the append-only property of the event store. Do this once when the new rule is implemented.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think Fowler's quote applies here. "For internal stuff..." - something like if the Customer class was debiting the account instead of crediting for `AccountCredited` events would be an easy fix without needing to alter the object's history. Just fix the object so the same history gets it into the correct state.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80186/discussion-on-answer-by-ewan-cqrsevent-sourcing-as-top-level-architecture-anti).

Comment: @Ewan I think Greg Young might be a more persuasive (and possibly more clear) source: https://leanpub.com/esversioning/read Specifically, the "General Versioning Concerns" section pretty much summarizes (oddly enough, almost point for point) the arguments I was trying to make.

Comment: https://twitter.com/gregyoung?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E313358540821647360&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.leifbattermann.de%2F2017%2F04%2F21%2F12-things-you-should-know-about-event-sourcing%2F